# JSX pass unescaped string literal as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, escaping

I have a jsx component `Editor` (draftjs) to which I am passing a `placeholder` parameter as follows:

```
return (
    <Editor
        placeholder = {htmlstring}
        [other options] />
)
```

The `htmlstring` variable is read from a json file and contains html tags. Unfortunately (in this case), react seems to auto-escape the string such that the tags are rendered as text (i.e. `&lt;` for `<`).

How do I pass an unescaped string literal to my `Editor`?

Comment: Agreed with @lilezek, and I'm not sure Editor neither escapes the placeholder string : https://jsfiddle.net/Lxkq9b0c/. Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now that you mention it. I guess I'll have to investigate other options.

Comment: Glad I could help ;-). Maybe your `htmlstring` is built with a function that escapes HTML characters in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Too late maybe.

If you want to display it as HTML then you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html